# Simplifying onClick function prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a React component where I am passing onClick function. I originally just had **button.onClick**, but I need to check if **isBannerClickable** is false before setting this. If isBannerClickable === true, then I don't want to set onClick.

Is it possible to simplify or clean this onClick prop?

```
onClick={!!isBannerClickable === false ? button.onClick : null}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would personally write it like this:

```
onClick={isBannerClickable ? null : button.onClick }
```

which is only different from yours in a few small ways:

1. `!!isBannerClickable` will always be a boolean, true or false, so there's no need to `===` compare it to `false`. You can just negate it - or remove one of your negations. So here it would become `!isBannerClickable`.
2. Then I've remove the `!` and swapped round the 2 remaining clauses. This is obviously exactly the same, and is more of a personal choice, but I always much prefer in `if/else` or ternaries to have the "positive" condition first.

Answer (score 1):

One way if isBannerClickable is not update frequently then you can use like this.

```
{ isBannerClickable ? <button onClick={onClickHandler}></button> : <button></button> }
```

But when the component in which the button is mount if reevaluates it will attach new onClick handler everytime.